# Программирование под Linux в Delphi

Tags: delphi, borland, linux

Хочу переходить на линукс, пока не определился на какой. Сам программирую на делфи, вот и не знаю, поддерживает ли линукс программирование в делфи. Слышал, что есть Borland Kylix, однако в интернете читал про него, что он долго уже не обновляется и поэтому устарел, есть ли нормальные среды разработки Delphi в линукс?

Comment: "поддерживает ли линукс программирование в делфи" - неверная формулировка. Вернее было бы спросить, "поддерживает ли дельфи программирование в линукс"

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я знаю, есть [Lazarus](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus). Попробуйте его.

Comment: А c++builder есть аналог у Lazarus?

Comment: Нет. Да и вообще есть куча других сред для С++. Например, QDevelop, code::blocks, u++ и многие другие

Comment: gcc :) а в качестве гуйни можно что угодно 
Анюту, Eclipse, code::blocks

Answer (score 1):

Можно Delphi под wine, но лучше использовать Lazarus.